# d3.js Force layout only applied vertically

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, force-layout, timeline

I'm doing a data visualisation with d3. To give you some context,

- the graph contains about 400 nodes (all data is loaded from multiple
  json files) that are connected to each other
- they are all mapped by year in a timeline (x axis)
- the position in the y axis is completely randomized
- the nodes have all different sizes

Now my question:
**How can I distribute the nodes in the y axis so that they don't overlap?**

You can checkout the full sourcecode on the [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/varusgarcia/Design-History-InfoVis) (work in progress - currently on the `real-database` branch).

This is a screenshot of how it currently looks:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Basically, in the tick() function, reset the nodes array x values to what you want them to be (presumably some scale to do with year), and the node and links will be drawn at those x values, and subsequent force calculations will start again from those values too

```
force.on("tick", function() {

    // Adjust to what you want nodePos to be, here I'm just doing it by index
    graph.nodes.forEach (function(nodePos,i) {
        nodePos.x = i * 15;
        //nodePos.x = xscale (data[i].year); // or whatever
     })

   // then normal node/link layout
```

I've forked this standard force-directed example by blt909 to show one way it could be done -->
http://jsfiddle.net/vztydams/

PS If you have a lot of items and very few discrete x values, best to give them a bit of wiggle room at first (i.e. a range in x they're contained to rather than a value), then slowly narrow that range down. Otherwise nodes will get 'stuck' behind each other.

Edit 02/03/16:

Hi Alvaro, essentially the graph.nodes is your linked data, as these are the objects that are attached to the displayed nodes as the data.

So if I set up a scale, and stick in a random year per datum:

```
var dom = [1994,2014];
var xscale = d3.scale.linear().domain(dom).range([20,400]);
graph.nodes.forEach (function(datum) {
    datum.year = dom[0] + Math.floor (Math.random() * (dom[1] - dom[0]));
});
```

...

We can then restrict the x position of each node's datum like this:

```
graph.nodes.forEach (function(d,i) {
    //d.x = i * 15;
    d.x = xscale(d.year);
})
```

(As I say, if you have a lot of nodes and few years, you'd be better restricting to a range and then narrowing that range down on each subsequent tick)

http://jsfiddle.net/vztydams/2/

Comment: Thanks, this this is a good help! We're using a date formatter to fetch only the year from our date: `(new Date(d.date_birth).getFullYear())`. How can I apply this to the `nodePos.x = i * 15;` ? We couldn't find a way to access the linked data.