# D3.js - Multiple Parent Dependency Tree with Swimming Lanes

Tags: d3.js, graph, tree, treenode

I can't find examples for displaying a dependency graph where nodes can have multiple parents. Nodes can be grouped in swimming lanes and can be interconnected between lanes.

How can I build a graph with nodes grouped in swimming lanes, that can be connected as a dependency tree?

The graph also needs to be horizontal scrollable.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20635480/constrained-d3-js-force-display and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35585192/d3-js-force-layout-only-applied-verticaly (my answer to a similar q)